# one to many collection onmodelcreating descending order

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

```
Public Class Payment
    Public Property PaymentID As Integer
    Public Property Amount As Double
    Public Property DatePaid As Date
End Class

Public Class Customer
    Public Property CustomerID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property Payments As ICollection(Of Payment)
End Class
```

Is there a way to define in OnModelCreating that the Payments collection should be ordered by descending DatePaid.  Such that the Payments collection will always start with the most recent Payment and end with the earliest Payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no there isn't.

You can do it with NHibernate - use `OrderBy` method in fluent mapping - but that's probably not going to help you. (Not that I am an NHibernate freak, by the way).

Even it it was possible I think I'd be very reluctant to use it, because I don't like this kind of stateful configuration of behavior. You're better off writing a repository method that returns the `Customer` with ordered `Payments`. That's the place where the query is created and executed, so that's the place where you want to define its behavior. - Just an opinion.